# What browsers currently support Web Workers?

Tags: javascript, browser, html, web-worker

I dug around, but couldn't find an authoritative list.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably I won't answer it better then [Web Worker Support](http://dev.pollenjs.com/web-worker-support/) statistic

**UPDATE:** since the link posted above is not working (strange, but "..reported as an attack page and has been blocked.." ) I've found another one, which is the most closest to the previous one (not the same, just the closest that I could find): [When can I use... Web Workers](http://caniuse.com/#search=worker)

Comment: @Maxym the link is broken (there is a warning saying there was a threat and the page was blocked)

Answer (score 3):

caniuse.com contains a comprehensive list of features for most browsers.

Here is the list of browsers that support web workers:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers

Answer (score 2):

According to [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29#Related_specifications) at Wikipedia, at least all major layout engines except IE's seem to support it.

Comment: I know this is a very old answer, (5 years at the time), but I can't stop commenting on the fact that 5 years later, IE is not a major browser anymore. I think they lost 70% market share in this time span.

Answer (score 0):

There are also some scripts available that will make your web workers backwards compatible with non HTML 5 browsers by running them synchronously.

This is one that I wrote recently: https://github.com/guyht/GWorker

This is another one I have come across but never tested: http://code.google.com/p/ie-web-worker/